# How to avoid the "Fail to request server version" exception, when analyzing code?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

Whenever I run a Sonar analysis using my sonar-runner, I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to request server version
     at org.sonar.runner.Bootstrapper.getServerVersion(Bootstrapper.java:73)
     at org.sonar.runner.Runner.checkSonarVersion(Runner.java:220)
     at org.sonar.runner.Runner.execute(Runner.java:150)
     at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:84)
     at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:56)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://localhost:8085/api/server/version
     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1626)
     at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:748)
     at org.sonar.runner.Bootstrapper.remoteContent(Bootstrapper.java:125)
     at org.sonar.runner.Bootstrapper.getServerVersion(Bootstrapper.java:71)
```

How can I avoid this exception and successfully analyze my code?

Comment: Which version of sonar-runner do you use? Is your SonarQube server up and running?

Comment: Could you please check the `logs/web.log` file contents of your SonarQube server? If there is something unexpected, please add it to your question.

Comment: Sonar Server / 3.6.2  and below error is there sonar.log               
 2017.08.21 19:03:18 ERROR o.s.s.p.Platform  Database relates to a more recent version of sonar. Please check your settings.

Comment: The database schema relates to a more recent version of SonarQube. You probably installed two different versions of SonarQube connecting to the same schema.